# toDataUrl() fails on a canvas element

Tags: canvas, qr-code, todataurl

I'm using [monospaced.qrcode](https://github.com/monospaced/angular-qrcode) in angular to generate a QR code

this works and generates a QRcode

```
<canvas class="qrcode" height="200" width="200"></canvas>
```

[image]

I'm trying to print this QR code by grabbing the generated image via toDataUrl(), but that crashes my application (I can't get a specific error, angular just says that my controller function is undefined when I add toDataUrl)

```
var printContents = document.getElementsByClassName("qrcode");
console.log(printContents[0]); // <canvas class="qrcode" height="200" width="200"></canvas>
var element = printContents[0];
var img = element.toDataUrl(); //this crashes angular
```

Not sure where this goes wrong, any ideas?

Comment: try .toDataURL() instead

Comment: Thanks kasoban, I guess it's time to get away from my keyboard for a couple of hours :)

Comment: Happens to me all the time. There I sit raging at my IDE for 20 minutes for behaving weird, then I realize I made a stupid typo in a directive name.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer below so I can mark this question as solved? :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is merely a little typo:

`element.toDataUrl()` should be `element.toDataURL()` instead.